# Excel showing weird thousand separator

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I use Microsoft Excel 2010 and my Excel shows thousand separators in a really weird manner. It has been doing so ever since I installed it, so this is not due to something that I changed later. You can see in the pic below how my Excel separates thousands in a big number:

[image]

This is through the default Comma Style format. I have even tried to make it custom by setting it to #,### and #,##0.00 but it still shows the same weird separation. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: silly question, but does this occur everywhere, or just in one file? if the latter, it could just be a string in text format, not a number.

Comment: Check the local format.  When you installed it you may have inadvertently chosen the wrong language.

Comment: Have a look at your Digit Grouping in the Regional Settings `Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional Settings > Digit Grouping`

Comment: @underscore_d This occurs in all my Excel files and has been occurring ever since I installed it.

Comment: @ScottCraner By local format you mean Number settings in Control Panel?

Comment: @garyh Tried but it doesn't fix the issue! :(

Answer (score 1):

By default, MS Excel uses computer regional settings when displaying number or date formats.

Go to Control Panel, `Regional Settings/Region and Language`(it depends by operating system) and select a different country if necessary, but especially check `Number Format` (Additional Settings). See `Digit grouping symbol` and `Digit grouping`.

Change `Digit grouping` to `123,456,789`:

[image: Digit grouping]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I tried this. The number grouping was fine in my settings and changing this to other groupings doesn't change the comma separator grouping in Excel. So this did not help. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: Did you install an Excel dedicated to a different language?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The issue was in the Regional settings. My Digit Grouping in the Numbers tab and Currency tab were **different**. Once I set them both to the same format, Excel stopped showing me the random grouping it was showing earlier.

Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction.